# Error in :: NA/NaN argument in Shiny R: Comparing Strings

Tags: r, string, matrix, shiny, reactive

So I am writing an app that lets the user input some basic operations involving a matrix. At one part, they are asked to "return" the entire matrix, as they would in base R, for which they can either "call" the matrix with rows and columns [1:5,1:5] or simply put in the matrix's name (my.matrix, for instance). I am not able to get the second part working, however, as the app will crash and return the following error:  Error in :: NA/NaN argument. I included the segment of code for this particular part in the server:

```
 observeEvent( input$go6, {
  sixthinput<- as.numeric(str_extract_all(input$six, "[0-9]+")[[1]])
  string6 <- str_extract(input$six, "my.matrix")
  sixth.list <- my.matrix[sixthinput[1]:sixthinput[2],sixthinput[3]:sixthinput[4]]

  isolate({
    buttonValue$go1 = FALSE
    buttonValue$go2 = FALSE
    buttonValue$go3 = FALSE
    buttonValue$go4 = FALSE
    buttonValue$go5 = FALSE
    buttonValue$go6 = TRUE
    buttonValue$go7 = FALSE

  })
  comparestring <- "my.matrix"

  if (isTRUE(identical(sixth.list, my.matrix)) & buttonValue$go6) {
    output$display <- renderText({
      paste(c("The matrix you extracted contains:"))
    })
    output$displayMat <- renderTable(
      sixth.list
    )
    output$display2 <- renderText({
      print("Correct!")
    })
  } else if(isTRUE(identical(string6, comparestring)) & buttonValue$go6) {
    output$display <- renderText({
      paste(c("The matrix you extracted contains:"))
    })
    output$displayMat <- renderTable(
      my.matrix
    )

    output$display2 <- renderText({
      print("Correct!")
    })
  } else {  

    output$display <- renderText({
      paste(c("The matrix you extracted contains:"))
    })

    output$displayMat <- renderTable(
      sixth.list
    )

    output$display2 <- renderText({
      print("Incorrect")
    })
  }

})
```

I am sure it has something to do with the variable "string6," "comparestring," and/or the part where I compare them in the if loop, but I am not sure where/how exactly it is going wrong, other than something is NA. Any clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in these lines:

```
sixthinput<- as.numeric(str_extract_all(input$six, "[0-9]+")[[1]])
string6 <- str_extract(input$six, "my.matrix")
sixth.list <- my.matrix[sixthinput[1]:sixthinput[2],sixthinput[3]:sixthinput[4]]
```

When the user inputs `my.matrix` with no subset operator (`[`), the value of sixthinput will be `numeric(0)` because there are no matching numbers. The value of `sixthinput[1]` will be `NA`, and you can’t then subset `my.matrix` by `NA`. The easiest way to avoid the error would be to check that `length(sixthinput) == 4`, and if not then avoid subsetting `my.matrix`.